# Multiple files with spaces in names as single argument in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have tool that merges multiple files to one:

```
totool=""test file1.gam" "test file2.gam" "test fileN.gam""
tool $totool outfile.wrl
```

Problem is that tool recognise space as file delimiter and "test file1.gam" will be treated as two files.
When I try do double quote variable argument:

```
tool "$totool" outfile.wrl
```

program try to open single file "test file1.gam test file2.gam test fileN.gam" instead of multiple files.

I try to escape double quotes around each file name:

```
totool=""\"test file1.gam\"" "\"test file2.gam\"" "\"test fileN.gam\"""
```

but program recognise escaped double quotes as part of file name:  Unable to open file '"test file1.gam" "test file2.gam" "test fileN.gam"' for reading

Number of .gam files is variable and $totool is defined in loop.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use an [array](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) in order to preserve arguments containing spaces, like this:

```
totool=( "test file1.gam" "test file2.gam" "test fileN.gam" )
tool "${totool[@]}" outfile.wrl
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an array is certainly reasonable.  Your attempts to quote can be addressed with `eval` and a single quote (escaping within double quotes will work as well, but using a single quote is much cleaner):

```
totool='"test file1.gam" "test file2.gam" "test fileN.gam"'
eval tool $totool outfile.wrl
```

Comment: This also works in test script, but it's harder to use this method in my working script. Thanks